# jQuery Add Tab Creates Extra Span

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a simple Tab setup using jquery.

I use the following function to create a extra jQuery tab and insert it where I please

```
$('#tabs').tabs('add', "ElementId", "Tab Text", intPosition);
```

The buy can be seen here.

http://jsfiddle.net/qKBUu/88/

The theme helps to clearly show that the latest tab that is inserted as a extra span around the text of the tab

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-2">
        <span>Delivery 66</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Can any one explain why it adds the span when adding tabs but not when creating the initally?

I believe this may be a bug of jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

That span is part of the default when adding a new tab. Check out "tabTemplate" option - http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-tabTemplate.

If you want to change the tabTemplate, just add in your own:

```
$('.selector').tabs({ tabTemplate: '<li><a href="#{href}">#{label}</a></li>' });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qKBUu/89/

Comment: but its not part of the default when creating a new tab? or if it is its not showing in the example for creating tabs... very odd but thanks very much!

Comment: It's not part of the default because you already have your HTML structure defined on the page as you would like. So if your <li> items that were already on the page looked like this:

`<li><a href="#tabs-1"><div class="foo">Delivery 1</div></a></li>`

Your "starting" tabs would reflect that whereas any new tabs that are created on the fly will default back to the jQuery tabTemplate option - http://jsfiddle.net/qKBUu/90/

Comment: maybe im a little confused but there example (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ under "View Source") shows they define there tabs without any span... So I assumed this is the "Default" way you should be creating your tabs. but then there "Default add tab" function puts a span in...